# tikz/pgf: compute width of \small text

Tags: tikz-pgf, width

In tikz/pgf, there is a function called `width("x")` . From the pgf manual, it returns:

> the width of a (horizontal) TeX box containing `x`.

After this sentence it starts to talk about things I don't understand:

> The quote characters are necessary to prevent `x` from being parsed. It
> is important to remember that any expression is expanded with `\edef`
> before being parsed, so any macros (e.g., font commands like `\tt` or
> `\Huge`) will need to be “protected” (e.g., `\noexpand\Huge` is usually
> sufficient).

I need to measure the width of some text with the `\small` modifier. However, I do not understand at all what `\edef` and `\noexpand` do. I have tried all of the following combinations:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{width("{\small My Text}")}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{width("{\noexpand\small My Text}")}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{width("\small{My Text}")}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{width("\noexpand\small{My Text}")}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{width("\small My Text")}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{width("\noexpand\small My Text")}
```

In all cases, the value of `\mywidth` ends up being zero.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here's an MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidthsmall}{width("{\small My Text }")}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidthregular}{width("{My Text }")}
        \node[draw] (node1) {\mywidthsmall};
        \node[draw, below = 0pt of node1] (node2) {\mywidthregular};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: Please, give a fully compilable code.

Comment: I think, you could need `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` for that. But without a running MWE I can't say more.

Comment: Inside the `tikzpicture` environment you need:`\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\mywidthsmall}{width("{{\noexpand\small} My Text}")}`

Comment: @Ross Is there a simple understanding for why this is the case?

Comment: My advice is to again edit your question and see if someone knowledgable about this can answer for you. In simplest terms, it is about how `TikZ` parses what it sees inside the `tikzpicture` environment. I would guess that it treats `{\noexpand\small}` together since it is in braces. Rather than executing `\small`, because we have used `\noexpand`, it is protected and saved for use with `My text` that follows.

Answer (score 2):

I don't got what is the deeper sense here. But `widt("abc")` gives a **point** value, because *width* is a *measure of length* and by definition it has *a unit of length*, in this case points.

So it is normally needed `\pgfmathsetlenghtmacro\name{widt("abc")}`, if this width shall be used somewhere,  which gives *the length* e.g. 12.34**pt** 
and lesser `\pgfmathsetmacro\name{widt("abc")}` which erases the unit points and gives *the number* e.g. 12.34

Whatever:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\sampletext{{\tiny My Text}}
\def\Sampletext{{\Huge My Text}}
\begin{document}
\section{tiny}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\mywidth}{width("\sampletext")} 
\sampletext~ has the width \mywidth

\section{Huge}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\Mywidth}{width("\Sampletext")} 
\Sampletext~ has the width \Mywidth

\section{pgfmathset\emph{length}macro}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
mystyle/.style={align=left,inner sep=0pt, anchor=west, draw}
]
\node[mystyle, draw, text width=\mywidth+1pt] (textbox) at (0,0) {\sampletext};
\draw[red] (textbox.north west) -- +(\mywidth,0) node[right=1mm]{\mywidth+1pt};

\node[mystyle, text width=\Mywidth+0pt] (textbox) at (0,-1) {\Sampletext};
\draw[red] (textbox.north west) -- +(\Mywidth,0) node[right=1mm]{\Mywidth};
\end{tikzpicture}

\section{Let's ruin it with pgfmathsetmacro, without \emph{length}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Mywidth}{width("\Sampletext")} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[
mystyle/.style={align=left,inner sep=0pt, anchor=west, draw}
]
\node[mystyle, text width=\Mywidth+0pt] (textbox) at (0,-1) {\Sampletext};
\draw[red] (textbox.north west) -- +(\Mywidth,0) node[right=1mm]{\Mywidth};
\end{tikzpicture}

Box correct, because \texttt{text width=123.4} (without unit)  sets points, as one would have written \texttt{text width=123.4pt}. \par 
Draw worse, because the default unit of TikZ is \texttt{cm}. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I get this using `\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidthsmall}{width("{\small My Text }")}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidthsmall}{width("{\small My Text }")} %<- added space
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidthhuge}{width("{\huge My Text }")}   %<- added space
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
Width of {\small My Text} = \mywidthsmall

Width of {\huge My Text} = \mywidthhuge

\bigskip

Try setting node width $\ldots$

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[text width=\mywidthsmall,font=\small,align=left,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {My Text};
\node[text width=\mywidthsmall,font=\small,inner sep=0pt] at (0,-1) {My Text My Text};

\node[text width=\mywidthhuge,font=\huge,inner sep=0pt] at (0,-3) {My Text};
\node[text width=\mywidthhuge,font=\huge,inner sep=0pt] at (0,-5) {My Text My Text};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `width("abc")` generates a point value, `\pgfmathsetmacro` makes a number of it. But Interesting: `text width=<number without unit>` sets a point value, so your code works. If you need your widths for `\draw` stuff, better use `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` which returns a point-value per default

Comment: See what I mean with:

`\node[draw, text width=\mywidthsmall,font=\small,align=left,inner sep=0pt] (A) at (0,0) {My Text};
\draw[red](A.north west) -- +(\mywidthsmall,0);`  The `\draw` will be only correct if you use `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro`.

Comment: @cis. Thanks for those points. I suggest you take my MWE, include your upgrades, and post what would be a better answer.

Comment: The point is just that TikZ uses the unit 'cm' by default, apparently except for `text width=<number without value>`, here it uses the unit 'pt'. 
Therefore your code will work as long as you only use these with `\pgfmathsetmacro` determined widths  in this place.
Since it is still not 100% clear to me what your goal actually is, I will not write a further answer for the time being.

Comment: What do you mean by "added space"? Do you mean the space after the final closing curly brace, or the one inside the curly braces for the `\small` command? What is the reasoning for this?

Comment: So it seems that you have to set the width outside the `tikzpicture` environment. Why does that happen? And how come the `width("x")` function seems to work inside the environment if you don't include `\small`?

Comment: It confuses me too and as I said the answer works only in special cases and it is mostly more TikZ-like  to say '+1pt'  somewhere instead of width("abc    ") to get a 'added space'